# Disabling requiredfieldvalidator not working on selecting radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I need disable the requiredfieldvalidator when UnitRebate radiobutton is selected. My code fails to do so .I have commented the logic that I have written which is supposed to be doing this.Is ValidatorEnable an inbuit jqueryfunction ? Can somebody help ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  $(".CashRebate").change(function () 
    {
      //ValidatorEnable($("#<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID%>")[0], true);
    });

$(".UnitRebate").change(function ()
        {
      //ValidatorEnable($("#<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID%>")[0], false);
    });
})
</script>
<table class="tableStyle1">
    <tr>
         <td>Rebate File Type
         </td>
         <td>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optUnit" CssClass ="UnitRebate" Text="Unit" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="Rebate" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optCash" CssClass ="CashRebate" Text="Cash" runat="server" GroupName="Rebate" /><br /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>    
     <tr  class="trValueDate">    
      <td>Value Date
     </td>
      <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatePicker1"></asp:TextBox>
        //<asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="ValueDateValidator" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Please enter the value date!" ControlToValidate="txtDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </td>    
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...it is working for me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
$(".CashRebate").change(function () 
{
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %>'), true);
});

$(".UnitRebate").change(function ()
{
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %>'), false);
});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about jquery. However, If you use the back end code of your file, then you can probably use the onchange event of the radio button and add this (Not tested, but I guess should work) :

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
```